# GCP VM startup script sed: can't read : No such file or directory

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, sed, terraform

I have a terraform GCP VM instance (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Minimal) metadata startup script which is defined via inline. The startup script downloads a file `config.toml` then edits the file `config.toml` via `sed`.
When I check the startup script logs via

```
cat /var/log/syslog
```

> sed: can't read : No such file or directory

My startup script for `sed`:

```
chmod -R 777 /pd-disk/config.toml
sed -i 's/http:\/\/localhost:8545/http:\/\/bor:8545/g' /pd-disk/config.toml
```

I know the command works properly if I SSH into the VM and manually execute the `sed` command:

```
sed -i 's/http://localhost:8545/http://bor:8545/g' /pd-disk/config.toml
```

What is the proper method or syntax for sed to execute within the startup script?

Comment: Does the username have some funny characters, spaces or something like that?

Comment: I apologize, I edit'ed the path. The config.toml file is located on a persistent disk. No unusual characters, that I think need to be escaped

Comment: Ah, the absolute path is visible for the user? Is it located inside of its directory or somewhere else on the filesystem?

Comment: Does `sed -i.bak 's~http://localhost:8545~http://bor:8545~g' /pd-disk/config.toml` work?

Comment: @MarkoE I believe the absolute path is visible to the startup script user (root), as root was responsible for formatting the persistent disk and the /pd-disk/ directory. I tried to ensure the privileges also with chmod 777 just to get it to work.

Comment: @HatLess Just tested, same error :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed command in many ways...

Below are examples to replace 'abc' with 'def'

- sed -i 's|abc|def|g' tmp.txt
- sed -i 's@abc@def@g' tmp.txt
- sed -i 's!abc!def!g' tmp.txt

In this way, you can use any delimiter as separator.